# How can I sum multiple spinners?

Tags: java, string, android-studio, sum, spinner

I have multiple spinners with a string array that has 3 items called "70","80" and "90". After the user selects these different spinner items I want to be able to sum up all of the items which the user has selected and display the total in a textview.For example a user selects "70" from one spinner and "70" from another, a textview will show the total 140. How can I do this?

```
public class FragmentCalc3 extends Fragment{

Context context;
TextView Results;







public static FragmentCalc3 newInstance()
{
    FragmentCalc3 fragment = new FragmentCalc3();
    return fragment;
}
public FragmentCalc3() {}
// Required empty public constructor

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator3, container, false);
    Results = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Results);



    context = container.getContext();

    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TestSpinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.GradeTest, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1); // Apply the adapter to the spinner

    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TestSpinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.GradeTest, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2); // Apply the adapter to the spinner

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            int spinner2Value = Integer.parseInt(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
            int spinner1Value = Integer.parseInt(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
            int Results = spinner2Value + spinner1Value;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });








    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: What's your code? Where are you stuck? This problem is very easily solvable if you just try.

Comment: please use edit button to add code to the question itself

Answer (score 0):

If you have two spinners `spinner2` and `spinner1`, And you want to get result when item of `spinner2` is selected then simply do like this,

```
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        int spinner2Value = Integer.parseInt(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString()); //Add try catch block if necessary
        int spinner1Value = Integer.parseInt(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
     int yourResult = spinner2Value + spinner1Value; //Result
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
     //Do nothing
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the Results variable is not being detected. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah i understand that but the problem is that after declaring the variable it is saying "Result" does not exist after int.

Comment: Be sure you have selected some value in both spinner